# How to access client-side window method in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, client-side

I am trying to change the structure of my app using DOM media queries inside Next.js. Normal media queries (CSS) work no problem. In "pure" React, I could do something like this:

```
function HomePage () {
  const [landscape, setLandscape] =  useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {

    const landscapeHandler = e => {
      console.log ("Change in landscape")
      setLandscape({matches: e.matches});
    }
   
    window.matchMedia("((orientation:landscape)").addEventListener('change', landscapeHandler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('change', landscapeHandler);
    }


}, [])
}
```

However, when using Next, changing the orientation of the screen doesn't do anything at all. Is  there a workaround? I always thought useEffect is client-side only and therefore the right place to do such media queries...
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js executes the code first in the server and then in the client. So, when it executes in server, window would be undefined.

You can do it like the code below,

```
 useEffect(() => {
   
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
     window.matchMedia("((orientation:landscape)").addEventListener('change', landscapeHandler);
    }
    // component Will Unmount
    return () => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.removeEventListener('change', landscapeHandler);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have used 'orientationchanged' listener, but I think it's depreciated.

You can try using the 'resize' listener.

```
 useEffect(() => {

    const handleChange = () => {
      

      const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth
      const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight
      
      const orientation = width > height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';

      console.log('orientation: ', orientation, 'width', width, 'height', height)

    }
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const unsub = window.addEventListener('resize', handleChange)
        return () => unsub();
    }

  },[])
```